# onDbClick in a span not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, event-handling, double-click

I'm trying to redirect the user when he double-clicks on a text. I tried this:

```
<span ondbclick="redir('/purchase/service/index/contractor_id/91');">Transalinord</span>
```

but the double-click event seems not to be firing. If I use onClick, eveything is working fine, which is driving me crazy. I'm using Chrome on a Mac. Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps ondblclick would work better then ondbclick?

Answer (score 2):

It is `ondblclick`:

http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/bL3kg/

```
<span ondblclick="window.open('/purchase/service/index/contractor_id/91');">Transalinord</span>
```